# why can't I move some of my tables with positioning?

Tags: html, css

I have managed to get certain bits of my responsive website to work but am still having some issues in terms of moving certain tables. For some reason, I can move the table in certain directions but not for others such as top. For the following table, I would like to move it lower if possible but even when placing the word !important after top, it doesn't work. For the first picture, I can't seem to move it further to the right and for the second, I can't seem to move it further down....

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlfRd.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlVn8.png)

This is the table code for the first problem

```css
.header2_user_information {
  background-color: #FAEBD7;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 110%;
  position: relative;
  right: 20em;
}
```

```html
<table class="header2_user_information">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">User\'s General Information</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>First Name:</th><td>Mervin</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Last Name</th><td>Lee</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Email Address:</th><td>piano0011@gmail.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>User ID:</th><td>piano0011</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Administrator Status:</th><td>None</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Moderator Status:</th><td>None</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Premium Membership Status:</th><td>Member</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The second is very similar to the first...

Comment: do I need to use table-layout:fixed?

Comment: Would you please add the html of your tables too? It's hard to tell what the problem is without it.

Comment: I will post the <table> code

Comment: This is strange... For the first table, I can only move it right but not left

Comment: For the second table, I can only move it up but not down

Comment: If you only want to make some space around the table, how about using `margin-top` or `margin-left`?

Comment: In the snippet, there is no problem with moving the table left or right or up or down; things like `right:-100em` and `left:100em` all work. So could you post a [mcve] that does demonstrate the problem?

Comment: And just some friendly advice: in your screenshot, there are various browser tabs visible... next time, crop.

Answer (score -2):

There is an explanation on when CSS offset properties can be used. According to FreeCodeCamp:

> When the **position** of an element is set to **relative**, it allows you to specify how CSS should move it relative to its current position in the normal flow of the page. It pairs with the CSS offset properties of `left` or `right`, and `top` or `bottom`. These say how many pixels, percentages, or ems to move the item away from where it is normally positioned.

You have `position: relative` in your code snippet but according to your question you probably forgot it in your actual code. Or you have overridden it somewhere else. (Use your browser's "inspect element" to check it.)

```css
.header2_user_information {
  background-color: #FAEBD7;
  position: relative; /* Note this line. It is necessary to use CSS offsets */
  top: 30px;
  left: 2em; /* px, em, percentage or any other value is acceptable */
}
```

```html
<table class="header2_user_information">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">User\'s General Information</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>First Name:</th><td>Mervin</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Last Name</th><td>Lee</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Email Address:</th><td>piano0011@gmail.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>User ID:</th><td>piano0011</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Administrator Status:</th><td>None</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Moderator Status:</th><td>None</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Premium Membership Status:</th><td>Member</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I am confused here because I did add the position: relative; follow by the direction

Comment: I don't think I have it overridden and I did try to add !important as well but didn't work

Comment: @LGSon According to OP's explanation in question, he doesn't know how CSS Offset works. This is the reason he got stuck. OP didn't provide a working example so I used his code and images to edit the question and add a code snippet. And here I present a minimal example with explanation on how it works. It can help him find the reason why his code doesn't.